# How to remove all fragments from back stack and show new one

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using fragments and push to back stack. So my scenario is like this I have fragment A, B, C, D ,E and I push them in this sequence **A -> B -> C -> D** and what I want I want to **remove A to D** from back stack and **show new fragment E.** Never show D or C.. or A, When back pressing fragment E Is there any way to ...